# How to loop through multiple columns. If cells exceed specific height then add a row and merge text in the above cell with empty cell below

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro to auto fit merged cells.  I combined it with another macro to loop through the spreadsheet and add a row below the cell that exceeds a cell height of 408.   The Macro does find cells in each column and will add a row if the cell exceed 408.  The problem is, the Macro only merges the cells in one Column.

My question is.  How do I get the Macro to merge cells in more than one column so that cell AB16 merges with the cell below in new row 17 and G11 merges the cell with new row 12.

Here is the code.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergedandSplit()
    Dim j As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MW As Double 'merge width
    Dim RH As Double 'row height
    Dim MaxRH As Double
    Dim rngMArea As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lng As Long, lastrow As Long
    ' ' Final_Test Macro ' Locate 409, Insert Row, Change Height, Merge Cells, Highlight ' ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+k ' Dim lng As Long lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Const SpareCol  As Long = 26
    Set rng = Range("G5:O" & _
        Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With rng
        For j = 1 To .Rows.Count
            'if the row is not hidden
            If Not .Parent.Rows(.Cells(j, 1).Row).Hidden Then
                'if the cells have data
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(j)) Then
                    MaxRH = 0
                    For n = .Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
                        If Len(.Cells(j, n).Value) Then
                            'mergecells
                            If .Cells(j, n).MergeCells Then
                                Set rngMArea = .Cells(j, n).MergeArea
                                With rngMArea
                                    MW = 0
                                    If .WrapText Then
                                        'get the total width
                                        For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
                                            MW = MW + .Columns(i).ColumnWidth
                                        Next
                                        MW = MW + .Cells.Count * 0.66
                                        'use the spare column
                                        'and put the value,
                                        'make autofit,
                                        'get the row height
                                        With .Parent.Cells(.Row, SpareCol)
                                            .Value = rngMArea.Value
                                            .ColumnWidth = MW
                                            .WrapText = True
                                            .EntireRow.AutoFit
                                            RH = .RowHeight
                                            MaxRH = Application.Max(RH, MaxRH)
                                            .Value = vbNullString
                                            .WrapText = False
                                            .ColumnWidth = 8.43

                                        End With
                                        .RowHeight = MaxRH
                                    End If
                                End With
                            ElseIf .Cells(j, n).WrapText Then
                                RH = .Cells(j, n).RowHeight
                                .Cells(j, n).EntireRow.AutoFit
                                If .Cells(j, n).RowHeight < RH Then .Cells(j, n).RowHeight = RH
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
        .Parent.Parent.Worksheets(.Parent.Name).UsedRange
    End With

    For lng = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Rows(lng).RowHeight > 408 Then
            Rows(lng + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Rows(lng).Resize(2).Select
            Selection.RowHeight = 409
            Cells(lng, "G").Resize(2, 1).Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .WrapText = True
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = True
                .ShrinkToFit = True
            End With
        End If
        If lastrow > 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("G5:AB100").Select
        End If
        lastrow = lastrow - 1

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think what you are attempting will give the effect you expect. Merging two cells will not allow more text to be visible. You could split the text so the first 408 points of text are in one row and the remainder are in the next. However, I find the result difficult to read since you can only see one row at a time. I prefer splitting into smaller units so you can read two rows at a time and get a slightly smoother scroll.

Comment: Thanks Tony.  The macro does allow me to view the cells after it goes through the autofit procedure. The problem is the second procedure. How do I get it to merge cells in more than one column.                                                                                                For lng = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Rows(lng).RowHeight > 408 Then
            Rows(lng + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Rows(lng).Resize(2).Select
            Selection.RowHeight = 409
            Cells(lng, "G").Resize(2, 1).Select

Comment: I did not know you could make the text from an overlarge cell visible by having an empty cell below into which it could overflow. I am sure I will find that useful. Your code looks designed to be difficult to update. You use rows and columns within a range then rows and columns within the worksheet. You hard code the use of column "G".  The first part processes row 5 to the last row. The second part processes the last row to 1. Do you need all this functionality? Do you have hidden rows? Do you have merged cells? What is the objective of `ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("G5:AB100").Select`?

Comment: I have the structure of the routine you seek but I am unsure what functionality to include.  I no longer think my earlier question about hidden rows is important.  The question about merged cells is important particularly multi-row merged cells. Are these cells formatted (e.g.: bold, underline, font name, font size) since formatting will affect the height of the text.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to know how to loop through a range of columns.   Maybe do one column at a time or do the whole worksheet.  There is some formatting in the cells.

Comment: You have to do the entire worksheet in one go. If a row contains two over-sized cells, you have to process them together. If you don't, you will insert a row for the first over-sized cell before discovering the second cell. I don't know how to handle a row that already contains a multi-row cell. Currently I an investigating why one of my routines in unexpected slow.

Answer (score 1):

**Introduction**

This answer took much longer than I expected.  Partly because I could not devote the time necessary because of other commitments but mainly because I encountered difficulties I had not expected.

**General advice**

Avoid working on the active worksheet.  If a key feature of a macro is that the user can select which worksheet to be processed by selecting it before starting the macro, then working on the active worksheet may be appropriate.  However, normally a macro processes a specific worksheet.  Specify that worksheet within the macro; do not rely on the user having selected the correct worksheet.

Avoid `Select`.  The normal reason for this advice is that moving around a worksheet selecting cells can be slow.  This is true but my reason is that it makes code difficult to understand.  You see code when the original programmer has selected one cell then selected an offset then another offset.  How is the maintenance programmer supposed to decipher what is going on? Few macros are written and then thrown away. Six months or a year later they need to be updated.  Techniques that might have saved the original programmer a few seconds or, worse, shown how clever then are, can take the maintenance programmer hours to understand.  Remember, you might be that maintenance programmer.

`With rng` ... `If Not .Parent.Rows(.Cells(j, 1).Row).Hidden`  I can imagine situations where it would be helpful to create a range and then operate within that range.  However, if sometimes you operate within the range and sometimes you operate within the worksheet, you are just making your code confusing.

`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(j))`  With an old version of Excel, I found two worksheet functions that were very slow when called with `Application.WorksheetFunction`. I keep promising myself I will investigate this issue properly.  Perhaps this was a fault in the old version of Excel.  Perhaps there is a huge overhead with `Application.WorksheetFunction`. I don’t know but if there is a simple VBA alternative, to a worksheet function I use it.

`If Len(.Cells(j, n).Value) Then`  Understanding this statement relies on the reader knowing zero can be used as Boolean True and non-zero can be used as Boolean False.  I do not like relying on such knowledge because if the reader lacks that knowledge, how do they understand this statement?  What would you google about that statement to discover how and why it works?

Please do not use variables such as j, n or i.  They just make your code difficult to read.

**Issues with your routine**

You use the following to calculate the width of a merged cell:

```
For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
  MW = MW + .Columns(i).ColumnWidth
Next
```

You cannot add column widths in this way and get a reliable answer.  If you look at the width of a default column with Excel, you will see: “Width 8.43 (64 pixels)”.  The 8.43 is the width in points which is the unit for width that VBA gives and expects.  To get the combined width you need to sum the pixel widths and add 1 for each internal border.  I have provided routines that convert points to pixels and vice versa.

**My approach**

I have kept your name `MergeandSplit` for the main macro although this name does not make sense to me.  However, I have completely recoded your routine and also have a number of subroutines and functions.

Many years ago, I did something similar but I did not know about merging multiple rows to make the entire content of a cell visible.  Once I had seen how you achieved this effect, I had no difficulty finding web pages that demonstrated this trick.  I did not find any of these web pages when I needed so my routine involved splitting cells.

When a cell exceeds the row limit of 409.5 points, you use two 409 point rows.  This makes for a lot of blank space if the cell is only a little bigger than the row limit and does not work if the cell needs more than 818 points.  I split a large cell into parts and calculate the combined height.  I based the number of rows inserted and the height of those rows on this combined height.  I believe the result is more satisfactory than you approach although my approach is not perfect.  If you split a cell, it loses all its in-cell formats.  By in-cell, I mean where parts of the cell are bold or italic and parts are not.  It is possible to determine the in-cell formats of the original cell and apply those formats to the parts but this process is impossibly slow.  I have deciphered the formatting in the past and been pleased with the results.  Perhaps I only used it on small cell because I had not appreciated how slow the process is.  I have a faster technique but not one I can provide quickly.  I have discarded the formatting when determining the cell height but applied a multiplying factor.  This multiplier works with my test data but you will probably need to adjust it.  See line 222 within my code.

I included a lot of `Debug.Print` statements to help me develop and test the macros.  I have left them all in the code below as an aid to your understanding the code.

I have tried to use simple statements that are easy to look up although my idea of simple may not match yours.  Try to understand my code on your own because that will help your development.  Come back with questions are necessary.

**Warning**: the macro works on the target worksheet which I have named “Data”.  Replace my name with yours.  Make sure you have saved a copy of the target worksheet before testing my macro.

Comment: Tony!!  Huge thank you for your efforts and looking into this.  I will review and get back to you as soon as i can.  Cheers

Comment: Hi Tony, for some reason the macro is not working.  When I run the macro on my worksheet, it doesn't find cells that exceed the 409. 
For example.  The first cell going down in my worksheet is G5.  The macro skips 5th row which contains cells that exceed 409 and does not auto fit, then autofits cells in row 6, then splits cells in G8 that exceeds 409.  I have cells in columns B, G, N, AB that exceed the limit. The macro does not find all cells and there's no common denominator that would cause it to skip certain rows.

Comment: Can you have a look at this module and let me know what needs to be done to scan through the whole worksheet and no specific columns.  If I can expand the range in this module the macro should be fine.

Comment: I tried to give my routine the same functionality as yours. For example, it ignores rows that are hidden and cells that do not have `WrapText = True`.  Could either of these be the cause of the skipped rows and cells?  If not, can you post the worksheet to DropBox or similar and post a link?  Alternatively, if you look at my profile you will find an email address.  Can you email me a copy of the worksheet?

Comment: I should say that my routine looks at every row and every cell with a value.  It could be defeated by merged cells at the edges because `Find` ignores merged cells.  It also ignores vertically merged cells because I can come up  with an approach that I think will give good results with vertically merged cells.

Comment: I cant send you the worksheet but can probably create something and send you the link.  I know the worksheet does have a lot of cells that are merged, wrapped, and does have hidden columns.

Comment: Also, not sure if its possible but the macro that i posted didnt work because i couldn't figure out how to apply a range of columns.  It does have to loop through specif columns.  I was just hoping to expand off of what was already there and target more columns.

Comment: My routine checks every cell with a value except in hidden rows.  It could be limited to specific columns if necessary but I would not advise it.  Your routine did not check for hidden columns and neither does mine.  Rather than create a new worksheet, it would be better to create a macro that replaces "a" with "x", "b" with "x" and so on.  This will leave everything important the same but remove any confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

Please see first part of answer for an explanation of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036413/973283

**Module containing MergeandSplit**

```
Option Explicit

Const RowHeightMax As Double = 409.5
Sub CalcRowHeights(ByRef CellHeights() As Double, ByRef RowHeights() As Double)

  ' On entry:
  '  * CellHeights has dimensions (1 to N) where N is the last column of a row
  '    containing a value.  It contains the height of cells 1 to N.  Cells
  '    within that range having no value or with WrapText=False are recorded as
  '    having a height of 0. For cells with a value and WrapText=False, the
  '    value recorded is the height of the cell necessary to view all its
  '    content even if that height is above the maximum for a row.
  ' On exit:
  '  * if none of the cells has a height more than the maximum for a row,
  '    RowHeights will have dimensions (1 to 1) and the value of the single
  '    entry will be the largest height of an of the cells.
  '  * If one or more cells has a height more than the maximum for a row,
  '    RowHeights will have dimensions (1 to M) where M is the number of rows
  '    necessary for the content of all cells to be visible. The values of the
  '    M entries will be the heights of the rows necessary to show the cell
  '    contents to best advantage.

  Dim CellHeightMinAboveZero As Double
  Dim CellHeightMax As Double
  Dim CellHeightsRemaining() As Double
  Dim InxCCrnt As Long
  Dim InxRCrnt As Long
  Dim RowHeightRemaining As Long

  CellHeightMax = 0#
  CellHeightMinAboveZero = 0#

  ' Find cell with largest height
  For InxCCrnt = 1 To UBound(CellHeights)
    If CellHeightMax < CellHeights(InxCCrnt) Then
      CellHeightMax = CellHeights(InxCCrnt)
    End If
  Next

  ReDim RowHeights(1 To 1)    ' Will always need at least one entry

  If CellHeightMax <= RowHeightMax Then
    ' All cell content will be visible within one row
    RowHeights(1) = CellHeightMax
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Not all cell content can be visible in single row

  ' Copy caller's cell heights to working array and
  ' find minimum non-zero height. Already have maximum.
  CellHeightMinAboveZero = 0#
  ReDim CellHeightsRemaining(1 To UBound(CellHeights))
  For InxCCrnt = 1 To UBound(CellHeights)
    CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) = CellHeights(InxCCrnt)
    If CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) > 0 Then
      ' This cell height > 0
      If CellHeightMinAboveZero = 0 Or _
         CellHeightMinAboveZero > CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) Then
        ' This cell height first non-zero height or less than previous minimum
        CellHeightMinAboveZero = CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt)
        'InxCMin = InxCCrnt
      End If
    End If
  Next

  InxRCrnt = 0      ' No entries in RowHeights() yet

  Do While True

    If CellHeightMinAboveZero = CellHeightMax Then
      ' There is one or more cell with the maximum height.
      ' There are no cells with any other height
      Call CalcRowHeightsAllocate(CellHeightMax, InxRCrnt, RowHeights)
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Allocate a row or rows for the smallest cell or cells or what
    ' remains unallocated of the smaller cell or cells
    Call CalcRowHeightsAllocate(CellHeightMinAboveZero, InxRCrnt, RowHeights)

    ' Reduce values in CellHeightsRemaining
    For InxCCrnt = 1 To UBound(CellHeights)
      If CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) <> 0 Then
        CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) = CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) - _
                                         CellHeightMinAboveZero
      End If
    Next

    ' Find new maximum and minimum
    CellHeightMax = 0#
    CellHeightMinAboveZero = 0#
    For InxCCrnt = 1 To UBound(CellHeights)
      If CellHeightMax < CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) Then
        CellHeightMax = CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt)
      End If
      If CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) > 0 Then
        ' This cell height > 0
      If CellHeightMinAboveZero = 0 Or _
         CellHeightMinAboveZero > CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt) Then
        ' This cell height first non-zero height or less than previous minimum
          CellHeightMinAboveZero = CellHeightsRemaining(InxCCrnt)
        End If
      End If
    Next

  Loop

End Sub
Sub CalcRowHeightsAllocate(ByVal HeightToAllocate As Double, _
                           ByRef InxRCrnt As Long, _
                           ByRef RowHeights() As Double)

  ' Add rows to RowHeights to give a total height of HeightToAllocate

  ' If InxRCrnt = 0, RowHeights() has already been dimensioned as (1 To 1)
  ' but entry 1 is unused.
  ' If InxRCrnt > 0, RowHeights() has been dimensioned as (1 To InxRCrnt)
  ' with entries 1 To InxRCrnt unused. A new entry must be added.
  ' In either case, InxRCrnt is stepped to reflect new state of entries.

  Dim NumRows As Long

  InxRCrnt = InxRCrnt + 1
  If InxRCrnt > 1 Then
    ' At least one new entry will be required.
    ReDim Preserve RowHeights(1 To InxRCrnt)
  End If

  If HeightToAllocate <= RowHeightMax Then
    ' The height to allocate is less than the row maximum
    RowHeights(InxRCrnt) = HeightToAllocate
    Exit Sub
  End If

  NumRows = Fix((HeightToAllocate + RowHeightMax - 1) / RowHeightMax)

  ' Make row heights as close to equal as possible
  ' 1 pixel = 0.75 points.  Height must be interger number of pixels

  ' Enlarge RowHeights for the extra rows
  ReDim Preserve RowHeights(1 To InxRCrnt + NumRows - 1)
  ' Calculate preferred row height and allocate to first new row
  RowHeights(InxRCrnt) = (HeightToAllocate * 4# / 3# / CDbl(NumRows)) * 0.75
  ' Reduce HeightToAllocate for height allocated
  HeightToAllocate = HeightToAllocate - RowHeights(InxRCrnt)

  ' Set remaining new rows, except the last, to the same height as the first mew row
  For InxRCrnt = InxRCrnt + 1 To UBound(RowHeights) - 1
    RowHeights(InxRCrnt) = RowHeights(InxRCrnt - 1)
    HeightToAllocate = HeightToAllocate - RowHeights(1)
  Next

  ' Set last row to remaining height to allow for previous rows not
  ' being the exact, preferred fraction of toal height to allocate
  RowHeights(UBound(RowHeights)) = HeightToAllocate

End Sub
Function CellHeightMerged(ByVal Wsht As Worksheet, ByVal RowTop As Long, _
                          ByVal ColLeft As Long, ByVal RowBot As Long, _
                          ByVal ColRight As Long, ByRef RowTest As Long, _
                          ByRef ColTest As Long) As Double

  ' * Wsht.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft) is the top left cell of an merged cell
  '   with RowBot and ColRight specifying the bottom right cell.
  ' * There is no code that would handle RowTop <> RowBot.
  ' * Wsht.Cells(RowTest, ColTest) is a cell below and to the right of any
  '   used cells.
  ' * The routine will use Wsht.Cells(RowTest, ColTest) and, if necessary
  '   cells below it, to determine the full height of the cell

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim WidthCombinedPixels As Long
  Dim WidthCombinedPoints As Single

  ' Calculate combined width of columns within merged cell.
  ' Excel VBA sets and returns column widths in points but the calculate must be
  ' in pixels

  With Wsht

    WidthCombinedPixels = 0#

    ' Calculate total width of merged cells in pixels
    For ColCrnt = ColLeft To ColRight
      WidthCombinedPixels = WidthCombinedPixels + _
                            WidthPixelsFromPoints(.Cells(RowTop, ColCrnt).ColumnWidth)
    Next
    WidthCombinedPixels = WidthCombinedPixels + ColRight - ColLeft - 1 ' Allow for interior borders

    ' Set width of test column to total width of merged cells
    .Columns(ColTest).ColumnWidth = WidthPointsFromPixels(WidthCombinedPixels)
    ' Copy contents of merged cell to test cell
    .Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowTest, ColTest)

    ' Use CellHeightUnmerged to determine height of test cell
    CellHeightMerged = CellHeightUnmerged(Wsht, RowTest, ColTest, RowTest + 1, ColTest)

  End With

End Function
Function CellHeightUnmerged(ByVal Wsht As Worksheet, ByVal RowCrnt As Long, _
                            ByVal ColCrnt As Long, ByRef RowTest As Long, _
                            ByRef ColTest As Long) As Double

  ' * Wsht.Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt) is an unmerged cell.
  ' * Wsht.Cells(RowTest, ColTest) is a cell below and to the right of any
  '   used cells.
  ' * The routine will use Wsht.Cells(RowTest, ColTest) and, if necessary
  '   cells below it, to determine the full height of the cell

  ' If a cell height exceeds the maximum row height, the cell content is split
  ' into parts so their total height can be calculated. For this to give the
  ' exact height, the separate parts must be split on a line boundary and must
  ' be formatted as the original. Unfortunately, when a cell is split, all the
  ' in-cell formatting is lost. It is possible to determine the formatting of
  ' the original cell and to apply that as approprite to the parts but this has
  ' proved to be impossibly slow.  A  multiplier applied to the height of a
  ' cell part is a crude technique but it gives good results with test data. It
  ' may (probably will) be necessary to experiment with the multiplier's value
  ' to get a statisfactory effect.
  Const Multiplier As Double = 1.08

  Dim AllRowHeightsBelowMaximum As Boolean
  Dim CellHeightTotal As Double
  Dim InCellFmts As New Collection
  Dim InxIcf As Long
  Dim LenCopy As Long
  Dim PosStart As Long
  Dim RowHeightCrnt As Double
  Dim RowNumCrnt As Long
  Dim RowNumMax As Long
  Dim RowTemp As Long
  Dim Text As String

  With Wsht

    If .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = "" Then
      CellHeightUnmerged = 0#
      Exit Function
    End If

    .Columns(ColTest).ColumnWidth = .Columns(ColCrnt).ColumnWidth
    .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowTest, ColTest)
    With .Cells(RowTest, ColTest)
      .WrapText = True
      .EntireRow.AutoFit
      CellHeightTotal = .RowHeight
    End With

    If CellHeightTotal = RowHeightMax Then
      ' Text does not fit into single row at current width
      ' Split text of cell into as many parts as necessary for each part to
      ' give a cell height less than the maximum. This is a crude split but it
      ' is not obvious that a better split would give better results.
      RowNumMax = 2
      ' Clear all formatting from test cells then set wrap
      With .Cells(RowTest, ColTest)
        .Clear
        .WrapText = True
      End With
      With .Cells(RowTest + 1, ColTest)
        .Clear
        .WrapText = True
      End With
      PosStart = 1
      Text = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value
      LenCopy = Len(Text) \ RowNumMax
      Do While True    ' Loop until row heights are all less than maximum
        ' Split text of cell into RowNumMax parts. This is a crude split but it
        ' is not obvious that a better split would give better results.
        RowTemp = RowTest
        For RowNumCrnt = 1 To RowNumMax - 1
          ' Copy early parts of text
          .Cells(RowTemp, ColTest).Value = Mid(Text, PosStart, LenCopy)
          PosStart = PosStart + LenCopy
          RowTemp = RowTemp + 1
        Next
        ' Copy last part of text
        .Cells(RowTemp, ColTest).Value = Mid(Text, PosStart)
        ' Calculate total height of cell is all parts below maximum
        CellHeightTotal = 0#
        AllRowHeightsBelowMaximum = True
        For RowTemp = RowTest To RowTest + RowNumMax - 1
          .Rows(RowTemp).AutoFit
          RowHeightCrnt = .Rows(RowTemp).RowHeight * Multiplier
          If RowHeightCrnt < RowHeightMax Then
            CellHeightTotal = CellHeightTotal + RowHeightCrnt
          Else
            AllRowHeightsBelowMaximum = False
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If AllRowHeightsBelowMaximum Then
          Exit Do
        End If
        ' RowNumMax was not enough rows to show entire text from cell
        With .Cells(RowTest + RowNumMax, ColTest)  ' Prepare another test cell
          .Clear
          .WrapText = True
        End With
        RowNumMax = RowNumMax + 1
      Loop
    End If

  End With

  CellHeightUnmerged = CellHeightTotal

End Function
Sub MergedandSplit()

  ' * This routine looks for cells whose row height is the maximum allowed
  '   indicating that not all the text within the cell will be visible.
  ' * If a row contains such cells, a row is inserted under it and the
  '   partially visible cells merged with the cell below it and the height of the two
  '   rows set so all the text is visible.
  ' * The previous sentence said "a row is inserted" and this is normally
  '   true. However, if a cell contains so much text that two full size rows
  '   are not enough to make it all visible, then as many rows as necessary
  '   are inserted.

  Dim CellHeightCrnt As Double
  Dim CellHeights() As Double
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastRowCrnt As Long
  Dim ColLastWsht As Long
  Dim ColLeft As Long
  Dim ColRight As Long
  Dim InxM As Long
  Dim InxR As Long
  Dim MultiRowCellWithinRow As Boolean
  Dim OpenMultirowCells As New Collection
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim RowHeightCrnt As Double
  Dim RowHeights() As Double
  Dim RowBot As Long
  Dim RowLast As Long
  Dim RowTemp As Long
  Dim RowTop As Long
  Dim Wsht As Worksheet

  Call WidthPrepPixelsPoints  ' Load arrays for pixel to point conversions

  Set Wsht = Worksheets("Data")

  With Wsht

    ' Find last row and column of worksheet
    Set Rng = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      ' The worksheet is empty
      Debug.Assert False
      ' Add code as necessary to tell user
      Exit Sub
    End If
    RowLast = Rng.Row
    ' No need to check worksheet is not empty since already know it isn't
    ColLastWsht = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

    ' Is is not possible to use "For RowCrnt = 1 To RowLast" becuase inserted
    ' rows would increase RowLast and the end value of a For loop cannot change
    ' during the loop.
    ' "For RowCrnt = RowLast To 1 Step -1" would avoid the inserted row problem
    ' but it is necessary to move down the worksheet so as to detect and
    ' process multi-row cells correctly.

    RowCrnt = 1
    Do While RowCrnt <= RowLast

      MultiRowCellWithinRow = False

      If Not .Rows(RowCrnt).Hidden Then
        ColLastRowCrnt = .Cells(RowCrnt, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Debug.Print "Row " & RowCrnt & "'s last column " & ColLastRowCrnt

        If ColLastRowCrnt <> 1 Or .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value <> "" Then
          ' This row contains at least one cell with a value

          ' End(xlToLeft).Column will not recognise a cell of a multi-row
          ' merged cell as containing a value unless it is the top left cell.
          ' If a multi-row merged cell is in the middle of the row, this does
          ' not matter because it will be detected as each column is examined.
          ' However, if a multi-row merged cell is to the right of any cells
          ' with values it will missed. If OpenMultirowCells is not empty,
          ' there is a multi-row merged cell that includes this row
          If OpenMultirowCells.Count > 0 Then
            MultiRowCellWithinRow = True
          End If

          ReDim CellHeights(1 To ColLastRowCrnt)

          ' Merged cells will always columns N, N+1, N+2 and so on making it
          ' easier to manage with increasing ColCrnt. However, stepping over
          ' a merged cell would not be possible with a For Loop so a Do
          ' Loop is necessary.
          ColCrnt = 1
          Do While ColCrnt <= ColLastRowCrnt
            With .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt)
              If .Value <> "" And .WrapText Then
                ' Cell has value and row height is to increase, if necessary, so
                ' the entire the value is visible.
                If .MergeCells Then
                  ' Cell is part of merged area
                  Debug.Print "Cell " & Replace(.Address, "$", "") & " non empty and wrapped and merged"
                  RowTop = RowCrnt
                  ColLeft = ColCrnt
                  Call AddressMergedCell(Nothing, Wsht, RowTop, ColLeft, RowBot, ColRight)
                  Debug.Print "Cell " & Replace(Wsht.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).Address, "$", "") & ":" & _
                                       Replace(Wsht.Cells(RowBot, ColRight).Address, "$", "") & " merged"
                  If RowTop <> RowBot Then
                    ' Rows with multi-row merged cells are ignored
                    Debug.Print "Multirow cell"
                    MultiRowCellWithinRow = True
                    OpenMultirowCells.Add RowBot  ' Record open multi-row cell
                    ColCrnt = ColRight
                  Else
                    ' Note: RowCrnt = RowTop=RowBot   ColCrnt <> ColLeft
                    CellHeights(ColCrnt) = CellHeightMerged(Wsht, RowTop, ColLeft, _
                                               RowBot, ColRight, RowLast + 2, _
                                               ColLastWsht + 2)
                    ' Advance ColCrnt to end of merged cell.
                    ColCrnt = ColRight
                  End If
                Else
                  Debug.Print "Cell " & Replace(.Address, "$", "") & _
                              " non empty, wrapped and not merged"
                  CellHeights(ColCrnt) = CellHeightUnmerged(Wsht, RowCrnt, _
                                          ColCrnt, RowLast + 2, ColLastWsht + 2)
                End If
              Else
               'Debug.Assert False
               Debug.Print "Cell " & Replace(.Address, "$", "") & _
                           " empty or non wrapped"
              End If
            End With
            ' For merged cells, ColCrnt has already been stepped
            ' for the extra columns within the cell
            ColCrnt = ColCrnt + 1
          Loop  ' While ColCrnt <= ColLastRowCrnt
          Debug.Print "Cell heights:";
          For ColCrnt = 1 To ColLastRowCrnt
            Debug.Print " (" & ColCode(ColCrnt) & ")=" & CellHeights(ColCrnt);
          Next
          Debug.Print
          If MultiRowCellWithinRow Then
            Debug.Print "Row cannot be processed because it contains a multi-row cell"
          Else
            ' CellHeight contains the height of every cell within the row that contains
            ' a value and WrapText=True. Some or all of those CellHeights can be more
            ' than the maximum height of a row.
            Call CalcRowHeights(CellHeights, RowHeights)
            Debug.Print "Row height(s):";
            For InxR = 1 To UBound(RowHeights)
              Debug.Print " " & RowHeights(InxR);
            Next
            Debug.Print

            ' RowHeights identifies how many rows are required to properly
            ' display the current row and the height of those rows

            If UBound(RowHeights) = 1 Then
              ' Only one row required
              .Rows(RowCrnt).RowHeight = RowHeights(1)
            Else
              ' Two or more rows required
              ' Insert extra rows below current row
              For InxR = 2 To UBound(RowHeights)
                .Rows(RowCrnt + 1).Insert
              Next
              ' Set row heights
              RowTemp = RowCrnt
              For InxR = 1 To UBound(RowHeights)
                .Rows(RowTemp).RowHeight = RowHeights(InxR)
                RowTemp = RowTemp + 1
              Next

              ' CellHeights identifies the height of each cell of row with a value
              For ColCrnt = 1 To UBound(CellHeights)
                If CellHeights(ColCrnt) <> 0 Then
                  ' This cell has a value. Calculate number of rows necessary
                  ' to for the entire value to be visible
                  CellHeightCrnt = 0#
                  For InxR = 1 To UBound(RowHeights)
                    CellHeightCrnt = CellHeightCrnt + RowHeights(InxR)
                    If CellHeightCrnt >= CellHeights(ColCrnt) Then
                      ' Will need to merge InxR rows to reach required height for cell
                      Exit For
                    End If
                  Next
                  If InxR > 1 Then
                    ' It is necessary to merge InxR rows for the cell's content
                    ' to be fully visible
                    ' Check for cell being multi-column
                    RowTop = RowCrnt
                    ColLeft = ColCrnt
                    Call AddressMergedCell(Nothing, Wsht, RowTop, ColLeft, RowBot, ColRight)
                    .Range(.Cells(RowCrnt, ColLeft), _
                           .Cells(RowCrnt + InxR - 1, ColRight)).Merge
                  End If
                End If
              Next
              ' Allow for inserted rows
              RowCrnt = RowCrnt + UBound(RowHeights) - 1
              RowLast = RowLast + UBound(RowHeights) - 1
            End If
          End If
        Else
          ' This row is empty
          Debug.Print "Row " & RowCrnt & " empty"
        End If
      Else
        Debug.Print "Row " & RowCrnt & " hidden"
      End If

      ' Clear any open multi-row cells that finished on this row
      For InxM = OpenMultirowCells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If OpenMultirowCells(InxM) = RowCrnt Then
          ' RowBot for this multi-row cell = RowCrnt so delete entry
          OpenMultirowCells.Remove InxM
        End If
      Next

      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1

    Loop

    ' Delete column that includes test cells
    .Columns(ColLastWsht + 2).Delete

  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see first part of answer for an explanation of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036413/973283

**Module containing global routines.  That is, routines I use in many macros**

```
Option Explicit

Dim PixelsForPointsUpTo1() As Double
Dim PixelsForPoints1Up() As Double

Public Sub AddressMergedCell(ByVal Wbk As Workbook, ByVal Wsht As Worksheet, _
                             ByRef RowTop As Long, ByRef ColLeft As Long, _
                             ByRef RowBot As Long, ByRef ColRight As Long)

  ' * If Not Wbk Is Nothing, it identifies the workbook containing the cell to be
  '   analysed.  Otherwise, the active workbook contains the cell to be analysed.
  ' * If Not WSht Is Nothing, it identifies the sheet containing the cell to be
  '   analysed.  Otherwise, the active sheet contains the cell to be analysed.
  ' * On entry RowTop and ColLeft identifies a cell.  If this cell is not part of
  '   a merged area then, on exit,  RowBot will have been set to RowTop and ColRight
  '   will have been set to ColLeft.  If this cell is part of a merged area then, on
  '   exit, RowTop, RowBottom, ColLeft and ColRight will identify the boundaries of
  '   the merged area.

  ' 21Apr06  Coded.  I wrote a similar routine some years ago but I cannot find it.
  ' 24Apr06  Changed RowTop and RowBottom to Long.
  ' 11Jun16  Changed ColLeft and ColBottom to Long.
  '          Tidied up old fashioned names.
  '  2Dec16  Replace workbook and worksheet names with workbook and worksheet references

  Dim Address As String
  Dim AddressParts() As String

  Select Case True
    Case Wbk Is Nothing And Wsht Is Nothing
      'The cell is within the active sheet
      Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).MergeArea.Address
    Case Wbk Is Nothing And Not Wsht Is Nothing
      ' The cell is within referenced worksheet of the active workbook
      Address = Wsht.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).MergeArea.Address
    Case Not Wbk Is Nothing And Not Wsht Is Nothing
      ' The cell is within the referenced worksheet of the referenced workbook
      ' A worksheet reference defines it parent.  Check Wbk and Wsht match
      Debug.Assert Wsht.Parent.Name = Wbk.Name
      Address = Wsht.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).MergeArea.Address
    Case Not Wbk Is Nothing And Wsht Is Nothing
      ' The cell is within the active sheet of a named workbook
      Address = Wbk.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowTop, ColLeft).MergeArea.Address
  End Select

  ' Address will be "$" ColumnId "$" RowNum [ ":$" ColumnId "$" RowNum ]

  If InStr(1, Address, ":") = 0 Then
    ' The cell is not part of an merged area
    RowBot = RowTop
    ColRight = ColLeft
    Exit Sub
  End If

  AddressParts = Split(Address, ":")
  RowTop = Range(AddressParts(0)).Row
  ColLeft = Range(AddressParts(0)).Column
  RowBot = Range(AddressParts(1)).Row
  ColRight = Range(AddressParts(1)).Column

End Sub
Function ColCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  Dim PartNum As Long

  '  3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  ' 28Oct16  Renamed ColCode to match ColNum.

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    Debug.Assert False
    ColCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

End Function
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
Function WidthPixelsFromPoints(ByVal Points As Double) As Long

  ' Convert a column width in points to pixels
  ' See WidthPrepPixelsPoints for more information

  ' This routine will return an appropriate value for Pixels even if the
  ' Points value does not exactly match one of Excel's value.
  ' For example, Excel has 12 Pixels = 1.00 Points and 13 Pixels = 1.14 Points.
  ' This routine will round Points 1.01 to 1.13 to Pixels 12 or 13

  '   4Dec16  Recoded.  Earlier version lost.

  Dim Pixels As Long

  If Points >= 1# Then
    ' Handle Points values over 1.00
    Pixels = UBound(PixelsForPointsUpTo1)
    Points = Points - 1#
    Pixels = Pixels + CLng(Points * CDbl(UBound(PixelsForPoints1Up)))
  Else
    ' Handle Points values up to 1.00
    Pixels = CLng(Points * CDbl(UBound(PixelsForPointsUpTo1)))
  End If

  WidthPixelsFromPoints = Pixels

End Function
Function WidthPointsFromPixels(ByVal Pixels As Long) As Double

  ' Convert a column width in pixels to points
  ' See WidthPrepPixelsPoints for more information

  '   4Dec16  Recoded.  Earlier version lost.

  Dim Points As Double

  If Pixels > UBound(PixelsForPointsUpTo1) Then
    ' Calculate Pixels for Points above 1.00:
    '   1.00 Point = 12 Pixels
    '   Above 1.00 Points, 1.00 Points = 7 Pixels
    Points = 1#
    Pixels = Pixels - UBound(PixelsForPointsUpTo1)
    ' Calculate whole points.
    Points = Points + CDbl(Pixels \ UBound(PixelsForPoints1Up))
    ' Calculate fractional points if any
    Points = Points + PixelsForPoints1Up(Pixels Mod UBound(PixelsForPoints1Up))
  Else
    ' Calxulate Pixels for Points below 1.00
    Points = PixelsForPointsUpTo1(Pixels)
  End If

  WidthPointsFromPixels = Points

End Function
Sub WidthPrepPixelsPoints()

  ' This routine must be run once before either WidthPixelsFromPoints
  ' or WidthPointsFromPixels are run.

  ' Excel accepts and returns widths of columns in Points. However,
  ' sometimes Pixels are required for calculations.

  ' One Point contains 12 Pixels.  Two Points contains 19 Pixels, three Points
  ' contain 26 Pixels and so on with each additional Point containing an extra
  ' 7 pixels.

  ' Note: this information only applies to column widths. For rows:
  '    Pixels = Points * .75.

  '   4Dec16  Recoded.  Earlier version lost.

  Dim Temp() As Variant
  Dim InxT As Long

  ' Accessing a Double array is faster than accessing a Variant array.
  ' I have seen it recommended but have not conducted my own time tests to
  ' determine if Double arrays are sufficiently faster to justify this
  ' two-step load

  Temp = VBA.Array(0#, 0.08, 0.17, 0.25, 0.33, 0.42, 0.5, _
                   0.58, 0.67, 0.75, 0.83, 0.92, 1#)
  ReDim PixelsForPointsUpTo1(0 To UBound(Temp))
  For InxT = 0 To UBound(Temp)
    PixelsForPointsUpTo1(InxT) = Temp(InxT)
  Next

  Temp = VBA.Array(0#, 0.14, 0.29, 0.43, 0.57, 0.71, 0.86, 1#)
  ReDim PixelsForPoints1Up(0 To UBound(Temp))
  For InxT = 0 To UBound(Temp)
    PixelsForPoints1Up(InxT) = Temp(InxT)
  Next

End Sub
```